# Multiple WebContent Folders in a Web Project

Tags: java, jenkins, ant

[image]

I have been tasked with developing Jenkins build for this legacy Java web project. To my surprise I am first trying to figure out what could be the reason to have two WebContent folders and is it even "OK" to have such a structure? Also, while packaging how should I list both the webxmls? This is what I have right now:

```
<target name="packageWar" depends="packageJars">
    <war destfile="../ear/${WAR_FILENAME}" webxml="Web Content/WEB-INF/web.xml">
        <classes dir="Web Content/WEB-INF/classes" />
        <lib dir="Web Content/WEB-INF/lib" />
        <fileset dir="Web Content" excludes="WEB-INF/lib/**/*,WEB-INF/classes/**/*" />
        .
        .
        .   
    </war>
</target>
```

Comment: The two folders in your image are not the same "Web Content" and "WebContent". There is a missing space in the second folder's name. Are you sure there is no typo somewhere ?

Comment: There are no typos, that is a screenshot.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up merging the differences into one Web Content folder and deleting the other as we realized that the other WebContent folder was not actually being used and needed to be deleted. This solved my problem without having to specify both web.xml files in Ant build script. Any better answer addressing the original question is most welcome.